# Moving a div when mouse near

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I want that the div I created will move when the mouse is getting near to him.

Here is the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/jLAq3/2/

Basic starting code (because I don't have a clue how to do it):

```
$('#leaf').();
```

Comment: Describe what you mean by "move"

Answer (score 2):

This is a start. Every time the mouse is moving outside the leaf then a message appears.

```
$('body').mousemove(function(e){
    var w = $('#leaf').outerWidth(),
        h = $('#leaf').outerHeight(),
        x = e.pageX,
        y = e.pageY;

    if(x > w && y > h)
    {
        console.log("The leaf is moving");
    }
})
```

Furthermore you can apply some css with js to the leaf for movement etc. In a more complex example you have to spot more carefully the position and not simply rely on the width and the height of the image.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a start.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lpg8x/80/

```
   $( 'body' ).mousemove( function( event ) {

if( isNear( $( '#near' ), 20, event ) ) {

    $( '#near' ).html( 'is near!' );

} else {

    $( '#near' ).empty();

};

} );           

 function isNear( $element, distance, event ) {

var left = $element.offset().left - distance,
    top = $element.offset().top - distance,
    right = left + $element.width() + ( 2 * distance ),
    bottom = top + $element.height() + ( 2 * distance ),
    x = event.pageX,
    y = event.pageY;

return ( x > left && x < right && y > top && y < bottom );

 };
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Bind a function to the movement of the mouse. As the mouse moves:

1. Get the coordinates of the element.
2. Get the coordinates of the cursor.
3. Compare cursor coordinates with element coordinates.
4. If cursor is near element, move element - else do nothing.

Easy stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic working example of how you actually would do all that
http://jsfiddle.net/jLAq3/10/

```
var leafX = 0, leafY = 0;
$('#leaf').css({position: 'relative'});
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    var offset = $('#leaf').offset()
        ,x1 = offset.left - 20
        ,x2 = offset.left + $('#leaf').width() + 20
        ,y1 = offset.top
        ,y2 = offset.top + $('#leaf').height() + 20 
        ,center, mousePos
    ;

    if(e.pageX > x1 && e.pageX < x2 && e.pageY > y1 && e.pageY < y2) {
        center = (x2 - x1) / 2;
        mousePos = e.pageX - x1;
        if(mousePos < center) {
            leafX += 20;
        } else {
            leafX -= 20;
        }

        center = (y2 - y1) / 2;
        mousePos = e.pageY - y1;
        if(mousePos < center) {
            leafY += 20;
        } else {
            leafY -= 20;
        }
    }


    $('#leaf').css({ top : leafY + 'px', left : leafX + 'px'});
});
```

But you should really learn the basics of DHTML before jumping into things, for example the difference between position absolute and relative, how to actually move HTML elements, layering, event binding etc.

Here are couple of good resources:
http://www.quirksmode.org/sitemap.html
http://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: @lllimar pihlamae  thanks a lot for all the info and your time!! if i may say it almost work as i want just i want the leaf will move automaticlly and not when the cursor touch it

Comment: @alonblack This is actually a very basic example, of how you would do something like this, but as you can see from the responses this is also fairly basic thing to do, I gave you the movement, because I get the feeling that you are an absolute beginner in DHTML and I could not find any good DHTML tutorial for you, but from this point forward you are on your own. I'll post the DHTML tutorial link as well, if I can find it.